clang-format: How to limit binpack-ed arguments length of first line
I have the following code:
function(aaaaaaaaaaaaa, bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb, cccc);
                                                 ^
                                                 └─ ColumnLimit

And the following .clang-format:
BasedOnStyle: Google
ColumnLimit: 50
IndentWidth: 4
AlignAfterOpenBracket: DontAlign

Then clang-format formats the code into:
function(aaaaaaaaaaaaa, bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb,
    cccc);

However, personally I don't like this format, I prefer the following (the second line is longer than the first line):
function(aaaaaaaaaaaaa,
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb, cccc);

I tried setting PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter to 0, 1, 10, 1000, however, none of them works.
I also really don't want // clang-format off. How to achieve that? Thanks.

I think there was an option to put every argument on its own line, if they can't be fit into the same line. Would that be acceptable?

@RefugnicEternium I'd like it to break into two lines, what I don't like is that clang-format puts arguments as many as possible in first line, sorry.

No need to apologize. There's so many different styles, it's next to impossible to cover them all with a tool you do not make yourself. Personally, when the arguments (or conditions) do not fit into one line, I like putting each of them into their own line and put the closing parenthesis on its own line. clang can't do that either, AFAIK.

@RefugnicEternium I'm quite curious how did you achieve your requirements finally? // clang-format off everywhere?

Nah. Clang inserts a line break, if there's an inline comment at the end of your conditions/argument. So, for complex conditions, a small comment detailing what the current line is for helps understanding AND code formatting.

@RefugnicEternium get it, thank you.

In my project, we'd write this on the first line... function(aaaaaaaaaaaaa, // ...to push the second argument to the second line.  That's to force clang-format to do what we want.  I'm not a big fan of putting in these comment droppings in order to pander to our formatting tool, but gotta do what ya gotta do.

@Eljay Thanks, I do use this trick currently, however, I'm also not a fan of doing this to pander formatting tool... But, that seems be the only acceptable workaround currently, sigh...
